# Cannot Assign Multiple Roles to Case

Tags: civicase

Using CiviCRM 4.6.

In CiviCase I was unable to assign a second role on a case. I need to have a Case Coordinator AND a second assignee.

In this case, an Event Rep. If I set the Case Type to use the `Case Coordinator` as the `assign To default`, my name appears in the case, but I cannot add a contact name to the Event Rep role.

If I set the Case Type to use the Event Rep as the default `Assign To`, my name shows there when I open a new case, but I cannot then assign a contact to the Case Coordinator role.

Always limited to just one Assignee. I saw some similar issues posted here late last year, but following that case they were supposed corrected.

I checked the code fix on this file: `CRM/Contact/BAO/Relationship.php`
(ref "[Fix for multiple role assignment between same contact cases #6439](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6439/files)" ).

My Relationship.php file matches the updated file, so I'm guessing it is something else.

Short screen vid showing what I am experiencing (1:37 min) here:

https://youtu.be/vYLhkqB9kY8

I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try this on the demo site? Just to make sure it is a problem in core CiviCRM rather than a specific problem on your installation?

Comment: No. Hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Tested on the 4.7 Demo site. No longer see an error message, but no attempt to assign a second role works for me. Nor does attempts to change the record for an assigned role. I keep reading the docs and it seems pretty straight forward, so I am at loss what I may be doing wrong, if anything.

Comment: This problem seems to happen only when the case is assigned to an Organization or Household contact, rather than an Individual. I've reproduced it myself under those circumstances, and can see from your video(s) that it's true in your case as well.

Comment: I have edited my answer below as i think it is the correct issue based on the youtube video. IN the video the Contact is Adams Family. Adams Family is NOT an individual. The Relationship Type of Benefit Specialist is for Individual to Individual - hence it fails (silently which isn't helpful)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue, certainly as per the youtube video, is because the Case Contact is not of type Individual, while the Relationship you are trying to use, Benefits Specialist, is only for Individual to Individual. This unfortunately results in a silent failure. So if there is any 'fix' required here, it would be to provide an error msg saying "this Relationships is not available due to mismatching Contact Types".

We hit a similar 'why can't we reassign a case to a new case manager' and the issue in our case was that Case Manager relationship was set to be Individual to Individual but in this case the Case Client was an organisation.

The reason we were able to create the Case Manager in the first place was because these were added via webform which seemed to create the Relationship despite the Contact Type not being appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your scenario on the demo site and I can add two roles with the same case role? You create the case and then the Case Coordinator (or any other role you set as manager) is linked. 
Once you have saved the case you can add more roles by clicking the 'manage' button. This will bring up the case, and if you click on the 'Roles' tab you see the current roles linked. From there you can add a role?

Comment: The "Assign Role" editing button simply does not record the name selection when on the case manage page. Here is a link to see what I am talking about. This is from the CiviCRM demo site. It behaves the same as my install.

https://youtu.be/Cr4CIGwKg7U

Comment: This has been an issue for some time I believe.  I remember discussing it on the old forums here https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=36229.msg154088#msg154088

Comment: pls see my explanation for why the failure occurs in the youtube example

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate the problem (Wordpress version): Roles defined in Case Types should be assignable from within the Manage Case window. But in my experience they are not; after going through the process to assign a contact to the role, the page continually displays "not assigned."

My Solution:

I have found that the way around this is to NOT add Roles in in the Case Types setup (Administer>CiviCase>Case Types). In fact I now delete the default Case Coordinator as well so there are no roles defined in the Case Type.

Now, after creating a new Case (Cases>New Case) I use the Add New Role button under Roles tab on the Case Management page to add the roles I need that have been defined in Relationships (Administer>Custom Data and Screen>Relationship Types. This allows a contact name to be assigned in the Role section of the Case Management.

I know this is not the way it Should work, but this is the only work around I've found to solve my issue. If you've got a better way (one that works from the Case Type Roles setup), I'd love to know it. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a bug.  I've experienced weirdness with Cases in 4.7 that could be explained by this, though I was so confused by that point, I can't really confirm that this was the exact same thing.  Others?

Comment: I believe there is still a bug on this and will attempt to get it reported.  When creating a new Case Type, either make sure there are no roles, or make sure that the Assign to Creator box is checked.  I also have not yet been able to edit old cases and assign a Case Coordinator.  (Manually add a case activity type 20 to the case activity table perhaps?)

Comment: I posted this bug on: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20853 It is still a problem on 4.7.21

Comment: the above jira has been noted as 'won't do' which I take it is same as 'rejected' with the comment "Kristine advises the issue was config" so there still seems to be some discussion required as to what is actually wrong and needs fixing.